# Sizing of an image, within a header, when creating a Responsive Design

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

How would I get an image, which is placed inside a header, to not change size (grow and shrink) when creating a responsive layout for the website? (So when I drag the browser left and right, it will stay the same size and have the same placement at the top of the page no matter what size I'm working with, whether it be a mobile size or desktop size)

Comment: please provide your markup. It all depends on how you've written it

Answer (score 0):

This sort of question is quite hard to answer without an example, but is ok to answer (it's just there's loads of combinations of achieving this functionality, it's choosing the right one for your situation is the difficult part)

This isn't a great example (as the image isn't very large), but using the combination of background and overflow, you can create this sort of effect:

```css
div{
  overflow:hidden;
  height:200px;
  width:100%;
  background: url(http://placekitten.com/g/300/300);
  }
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Note, the image isn't changing size, but cropping instead (you don't see its paws, for example, as they are 'cropped').

---

Without Using a background image

If, however, you were using simply a `<img>` tag instead, you could use (again) a similar approach. this one wraps your image in a parent div, and then set overflow to hidden to hide any 'extra image'

```css
div {
  height: 300px;
  width: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/300/300" />
</div>

note: the image is 300 by 300px in size, but won't 'stretch', but in fact crop.
```

Comment: Thank you! I figured it out!